# Приведение типов для передачи на sql-сервер

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Всем привет.

Есть куча экселей из которых надо собрать данные и выгрузить в таблицу на ms sql сервере. Таблицы в файлах Эксель и на сервере имеют одинаковую структуру. Всего 157 параметров (столбцов) определенных типов.

Наверно, эти данные  можно поместить в словарь (название столбца : значение) `Dictionary<string, object>`. Но сможет ли значение словаря типа `object` быть автоматически приведено к нужному типу при загрузке на сервер? Или лучше использовать `var` или `dynamic`?

Типы данных таблицы на сервере: `int, float, date, varchar(100 - 4000)`

Comment: Какие типы данных присутствуют? Все перечислите

Comment: Андрей, добавил инфу в основное сообщение

Comment: Передавайте данные просто как строки (`Dictionary<string, string>`), приведение типов будет происходить на стороне сервера (будьте внимательны с форматом даты)

Comment: Этот процесс будет повторяться или это разовая акция? Если это разовая акция и Ваши данные по структуре одинаковые, то я бы Вам рекомендовал не изобретать велосипед. Импортируйте ексел таблицы в базу данных напрямую.

Comment: Регулярная операция. пользователи скидывают на сетевой диск анкету в формате эксель, а задача программы - раз в сутки собирать из этих анкет данные и отгружать их на сервер

Comment: @WinnerIT анкет может быть очень много и обрабатывать каждую очень долго

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
INTO #t
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=file.xlsx;', 'SELECT * FROM [Лист1$]') AS a;

SELECT *
FROM #t;
```

Попробуйте так. Можно обойтись без C#, используя `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: Спасибо, но если бы файлов было не так много, то можно было бы вообще через стандартный экспорт/импорт работать. Однако файлов будет много и возникла подзадача - грузить это все еще и в Oracle DB, для которой, к слову, нам даже никакого клиента не поставили. Вот вам логин, пароль, строка подключения кудрявая. Грузите, как хотите :)

Comment: Ну дело конечно хозяйское, но файлы можно ведь перебором обходить и с сервера, зато нативная можно сказать загрузка и приведение типов. А в случае с ораклом можно через связанный сервер тоже попробовать

Comment: А много файлов - это сколько?